# Identical methods act differently in VS debug console and Unity debug console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to sort 25 numbers (0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... , 12, 12) randomly in Unity.

First, I wrote a test code in VS.

[Program.cs]

```
using System;

namespace random {
    class Shuffle {
        // ShuffleNumbers: sort 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... 12, 12 (25 numbers) randomly
        public static int[] ShuffleNumbers() {

            // randomArray : randomly sorted numbers
            int[] randomArray = new int[25];

            // howManyCanBeAdded[k] : how many 'k's can be added in randomArray
            int[] howManyCanBeAdded = new int[13] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

            // r : Random object
            System.Random r = new System.Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; ) {
                // create a random number
                int random = r.Next(0, 13);

                // check whether the number can be added
                // if true, add the number to randomArray
                if (howManyCanBeAdded[random] > 0) {
                    howManyCanBeAdded[random]--;
                    randomArray[i++] = random;
                }
            }

            return randomArray;
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] randomArray = random.Shuffle.ShuffleNumbers();
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                Console.Write(randomArray[i]);
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It acted correctly in VS debug console, like this:

[image]

So I pasted the code in Unity script.

[Shuffle.cs]

```
using System;

public class Shuffle
{
    // ShuffleNumbers: sort 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... 12, 12 (25 numbers) randomly
    public static int[] ShuffleNumbers() {

        // randomArray : randomly sorted numbers
        int[] randomArray = new int[25];

        // howManyCanBeAdded[k] : how many 'k's can be added in randomArray
        int[] howManyCanBeAdded = new int[13] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

        // r : Random object
        System.Random r = new System.Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; ) {
            // create a random number
            int random = r.Next(0, 13);

            // check whether the number can be added
            // if true, add the number to randomArray
            if (howManyCanBeAdded[random] > 0) {
                howManyCanBeAdded[random]--;
                randomArray[i++] = random;
            }
        }

        return randomArray;
    }
}
```

[ShuffleObject.cs]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShuffleObject : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        int[] randomArray = Shuffle.ShuffleNumbers();
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            Debug.Log(randomArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I drag&dropped ShuffleObject.cs file to an empty object in the scene and played.

But the Unity debug console acted differently. It printed only 13 numbers(0, 1, 2, ..., 12).

Why the same code act differently in VS and Unity?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should consider filling an array with the numbers you want and then swapping positions of 2 random indices enough time to get your number in randomized position in your array. Like you will do when you mix a deck of cards... If you do so, swapping 4 times the size of your array should be enough.

Comment: In your code, you've allowed for how many could be added but if it was 0 you dont pick a new number. Therefore you arent necessarily going to get 25 good numbers

Comment: Your printing for loop iterates 25 times (the code is pretty straightforward). It would either throw an out of bounds exception or print **something**. There must be more logs than the screenshot you added.

Comment: @BugFinder he anyway goes through all 25 entries. It is just possible that some of them stay `0` which is the default value of `int`.

Comment: I’d imagine collapsed log and some has more than one entry so only the original numbers show but there’s counters in the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure in Unity you have [`Collapse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html) deactivated on the console options (second from left)!

> Shows only the first instance of recurring error messages.
>
> This is useful for run-time errors, such as null references, that are sometimes generated on each frame update.

If the same number is logged twice Unity automatically groups them together in one message but with a small `2` or other number on the left side indicating this exact message was logged multiple times.

Since you can return numbers from `0` to `12` it is very probable you get some of the numbers multiple times. So you see them collapsed and it appears to be only exactly 13 messages (your possible values).